# Dynamically created rectangles that can be moved and snapped to each other in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms Application in which I would like to be able to dynamically create rectangles (either as pictureboxes or with graphics.drawrectangle) that can be moved by the mouse (for instance with Mouse_Move) and snap to each other without overlapping (they should be able to overlap while moving, but not when in position). The size of a rectangle is set beforehand and is fixed, so no resizing, and the rectangles should be confined to a panel.

This block of code confines the rectangle to an area (in my case the same area as a panel) that is 400 pixels wide and 2500 pixels high when dragging it and any **picturebox** that is created during runtime by adding a mousemove add-handler to them. There might be better ways to achieve this (please feel free to improve!) but this seems to do the trick if pictureboxes are used:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Dim picBox As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    Static mousePosX As Single
    Static mousePosY As Single
    Dim currentx As Single
    Dim currenty As Single

    If e.Button = 0 Then
        mousePosX = e.X
        mousePosY = e.Y
    Else
        currentx = picBox.Left + (e.X - mousePosX)
        currenty = picBox.Top + (e.Y - mousePosY)

        If Not (currentx < 0 Or currentx + picBox.Width > 400) Then
            picBox.Left = currentx
        End If
        If Not (currenty < 0 Or currenty + picBox.Height > 2500) Then
            picBox.Top = currenty
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the code posted [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_23401334.html) is a way to make a number of pictureboxes "snap" to each other when moved similar to the way I visualize them doing. I hope you get the idea of what I'm after.

As an added bonus, if possible, I would like to also be able to create circles that act the same way as well as when finished creating and moving all of the shapes, be able to save all of them in one big picture, standalone or in a PDF/Word page.

I should also add that I'm doing this as a hobby on the side and have only read a book or two about VB.Net and other than that I'm self thought through reading posts on forums like these and the examples and guides on Microsoft Developer Network. As a result, to be able to learn i would very much appreciate if you're able to explain what is happening!

I very much appreciate all and any of your help in this matter!

Regards,
William

Comment: the VB PowerPack addon has an actual Rectangle control which might do about half of what it seems like you are wanting to do.  You have a project description there and SO is more geared towards distinct programming questions.

Comment: That's very interesting and I thank you for your help. I will continue reading up on the PowerPack shapes. English is not my first language and I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence. Do you mean that this question is posted under the wrong topic on this forum?

Comment: I think he's trying to say that you're not asking for a specific problem's solution, but en entire project/goal. If you're having a problem with something specific, tell us what you've tried, what errors, if any, you've encountered, etc.

Comment: If you're wanting to "snap" edges, I'd imagine the easiest way would be to store the existing edges(obvious and easy), then compare the one you're holding (the new one) to see if it's within say 5 pixels of one of the stored rectangles' edges.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help provided in the comment section of my original post. I've managed to create something that does exactly what I want and might as well share the code in hopes of someone finding it useful. Below is the code:

```
    Private startX, startY As Integer
Private Shapes As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private Const SnapDistance As Integer = 5
Private Sub pb_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    pb.BringToFront()

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        startX = e.X
        startY = e.Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pb_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        Dim newPt As New Point(pb.Location.X - (startX - e.X), pb.Location.Y - (startY - e.Y))

                For Each shape As PictureBox In panel.Controls

                    If Not (shape Is pb) Then

                        'If there are several objects (picturebox)
                        If Math.Abs(newPt.Y - (shape.Location.Y + shape.Height)) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, shape.Location.Y + shape.Height)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs(newPt.Y - shape.Location.Y) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, shape.Location.Y)

                        End If
                        If Math.Abs(newPt.X) <= 20 Then
                            newPt = New Point(0, newPt.Y)
                        ElseIf (newPt.X) < 0 Then
                            newPt = New Point(0, newPt.Y)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs(newPt.X - (shape.Location.X + shape.Width)) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(shape.Location.X + shape.Width, newPt.Y)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs(newPt.X - shape.Location.X) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(shape.Location.X, newPt.Y)
                        End If

                        If (newPt.X + pb.Width) > 400 Then
                            newPt = New Point(400 - pb.Width, newPt.Y)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs((newPt.X + pb.Width) - shape.Location.X) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(shape.Location.X - pb.Width, newPt.Y)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs((newPt.X + pb.Width) - (shape.Location.X + shape.Width)) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point((shape.Location.X + shape.Width) - (pb.Width), newPt.Y)
                        End If

                        If (panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y + newPt.Y + pb.Height) > 2500 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, 2500 - pb.Height)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs((newPt.Y + pb.Height) - shape.Location.Y) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, shape.Location.Y - pb.Height)
                        ElseIf Math.Abs((newPt.Y + pb.Height) - (shape.Location.Y + shape.Height)) <= SnapDistance Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, (shape.Location.Y + shape.Height) - (pb.Height))
                        End If

                        If (newPt.Y - panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y) < 0 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y)
                        ElseIf panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y = 0 And Math.Abs(newPt.Y) <= 20 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, 0)
                        End If

                        If (newPt.Y + pb.Height + Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y)) > 2500 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, 2500 - pb.Height - Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y))
                        End If

                    Else
                        'If there are only one object (picturebox)
                        If (newPt.Y - panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y) < 0 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y)
                        ElseIf panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y = 0 And Math.Abs(newPt.Y) <= 20 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, 0)
                        End If

                        If Math.Abs(newPt.X) <= 20 Or (newPt.X) < 0 Then
                            newPt = New Point(0, newPt.Y)
                        End If

                        If (newPt.X + pb.Width) > 400 Then
                            newPt = New Point(400 - pb.Width, newPt.Y)
                        End If

                        If (newPt.Y + pb.Height + Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y)) > 2500 Then
                            newPt = New Point(newPt.X, 2500 - pb.Height - Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y))
                        End If

                    End If
                Next

            End If
        Next
        pb.Location = newPt
        End If
End Sub
```

Thanks once again all of you who gave your support and took your time to help me!